# OpenVPN through stunnel routing issues

Tags: openvpn, stunnel

I know this has been asked and answered many times, but i just can't make it work: I have a raspberry pi as an stunnel and openvpn server and an ubuntu client but although the connections seem correct, whenever I use the VPN all my internet is lost in the client side. Through lots of searching and reading this seem to be a routing problem, but I can't figure out where (the raspberry pi is located in 193.168.2.31 with ipv4 forwarding enabled, with public ip fake.ddns.net). The config files are as follows:

server stunnel:

```
foreground=yes
chroot = /var/lib/stunnel4
pid = /stunnel4.pid
setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
[openvpn]
accept = 443
connect = localhost:1194
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

server openvpn:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "192.168.2.31 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

client stunnel:

```
foreground = yes
[openvpn]
client = yes  
accept = 1194
connect = fake.ddns.net:443
cert = stunnel.pem
```

client openvpn

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote localhost 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>...</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
<tls-auth>...</tls-auth>
```

It may be worth noting that I also have privoxy installed on the raspberry pi and when I use just stunnel (other configs, better explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/794857/redirect-all-web-traffic-through-tls-without-a-vpn)) everything works just fine

Thanks for the patience!!

As suggested by @Andy, here is the output of `ip route show`:

> 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0  default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
>   10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
>   127.0.0.1 via 192.168.2.1 dev wlp2s0 
>   128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
>   192.168.2.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.100 metric 600 
>   192.168.2.31 dev wlp2s0 scope link

Comment: Can you run `route print` (Windows) or `ip route show` (Linux) on your client?
I think you are missing a `push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.31 1"` on your server config.

Comment: Hi, Andy. Thanks for your quick response. I updated my questions to show the output for my ubuntu client.

Comment: You have the routes, so, no, you werent missing a route push command.

Answer (score 0):

finally "brute forced" the answer, randomly adding or removing config parameters although biased to routing issues. I changed the `route 192.168.2.31 255.255.255.255 net_gateway` from server to client and now it works. So, now the openvpn configs are as follows:

server openvpn:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

client openvpn

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote localhost 1194
route fake.ddns.net 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>...</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
<tls-auth>...</tls-auth>
```

I have no idea what is the difference so please anyone who understand add to this solution